# Videos/memes with iMessage app

Tags: imessage, imessage-extension, imessagefilter

I was trying to add small videos in iMessage app but videos not showing in my MSStickerBrowserViewController. I used below code to add videos/

let sticker = try MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: "")
stickers.append(sticker)

Is it possible to add videos there?

Thank you,

Comment: It is used to show the image rather than video

Comment: We can use videos too using custom iOS app but I'm not able to add.

Comment: custom iOS App and Message Extension. I don't understand the context.

Comment: I mean Custom iMessage app with Message extension.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages/msconversation